# Execute All Functions In A Script

Tags: powershell

If I have a script with some functions such as:

```
function FunctionOne{}
function FunctionTwo{}
```

How can I call them all in one line, in the same script, without having to specify the name of each function?

I'd like to do something like:

```
Call-AllFunctionsInCurrentScriptConsecutively #calls FunctionOne then FunctionTwo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](https://d-fens.ch/2015/04/26/nobrainer-enumerate-all-functions-in-a-powershell-script-file-via-ast/) suggests using [`ParseFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile) for parsing the script:

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.ps1'

[ref]$tokens      = $null
[ref]$parseErrors = $null
$ast = [Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($filename, $tokens, $parseErrors)
```

Then you can invoke the functions (after you dot-sourced the script) via the call operator:

```
$ast.EndBlock.Statements | Where-Object { $_.Name } | ForEach-Object { & $_.Name }
```

For using this from within a script replace the filename with `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'd like to do this in the same script.

Comment: Thanks. That worked well. I just had to change $ast.EndBlock.Statements | ForEach-Object { & $_.Name } to $ast.EndBlock.Statements | Where-Object { ![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Name) } | ForEach-Object { & $_.Name }

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to add that. `Where-Object { $_.Name }` would suffice, though.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the file and grabbing the function names from the AST is probably the most reliable option.

A more low-tech approach would be to simply diff the function list before and after sourcing the script:

```
$InitialFunctions = Get-ChildItem function: -Name
. C:\path\to\script.ps1
Get-ChildItem function: -Name |Where-Object {$InitialFunctions -notcontains $_} |ForEach-Object {
    & $_
}
```