# Extracting the param block from script

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to extract the param block of a PowerShell script.
I have read that is possible with the AST parser but I can't find a helpful snippet.

I have this Here-String and I only want to extract the param block as string.

```
$scriptBlock = @'
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][switch]$param3
)
Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)
'@
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029306/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Ansgar Wiechers for the inspiration.

I found a way to solve this problem. That's the working solution:

```
$scriptBlock = @'
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][switch]$param3
)
Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)
'@

[ref]$tokens = $null
[ref]$parseErrors = $null
$paramBlock = ([Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($scriptBlock, $parseErrors,$tokens)).ParamBlock.toString()
```